# How to mimic fnIsOpen() with jQuery DataTables 1.8.x

Tags: datatables

I'm using fnOpen, fnClose functions of jQuery DataTables.
How can I check if given TR is currently opened or not ?

In version 1.9 there is fnIsOpen but I'm using 1.8 and can't upgrade.

It is not required to keep the state of rows on pagination / filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was creating a attr over the item to click and setting it everytime

```
$('#Table tbody td img').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    oTable = $('#Table').dataTable();

    if ( $(this).attr("isOpen") == "true" )
    {
        // This row is already open - close it
        this.src = "/gfx/thumb-delete.png";
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        $(this).attr("isOpen","false");
    }
    else
    {
        // Open this row (if attr isOpen is not set, set it)
        this.src = "/gfx/thumb-delete.png";
        oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
        $(this).attr("isOpen","true");
    }
});
```

Comment: I did something similar, eventually